# IIS ARR & load balancing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, load-balancing, arr

I set up ARR on my front server and I deployed my web application (asp.net mvc) on two servers: server1 & servr2;
I followed the instruction in the [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing) but my ARR server doesn't load balance correctly; it always redirect to one server (server1) and when I turn off server1 then it redirects to server2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do both servers show up as `Healthy` under `Monitoring and Management`? What is are your Load Balancing` settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I think it is because ARR is located on server1. And after it redirects to itself it do this again until it redirects to server 2.

I added condition for url rewrite rule for {HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR} and pattern .+
Additionally i used regex for whole rule and replaced * for .+ everywhere

And it works for me!

I noticed that chrome cached pages. IE is switching between servers more often.

Comment: You are not 100% right. One of solutions is to put ARR on a different server. It is not clear from my answer. Actually i found solution and edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Set your Load balance algorithm to "Weighted round robin". This algorithm will route the request to all your servers equally.