# IIS 10 ARR LoadBalancer Working more like Redundent Web Servers

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10, arr, web-farm

We have configured a new webfarm using IIS10 with 3 hosts operating with the web traffic with a loadbalancing IIS ARR3.0 server sitting infront to balance incoming requests between all the nodes. During initial testing (Basic HTML pages) the round robin setup (33.33%) distribution between each node was working well but we had to enable server / client affinity so that our applications kept a consistent connection between our client session and the application. Since then, we are finding that all traffic going to these applications originating from different machines on different networks are all being forwarded to the same application server. If you take the server offline the application seamlessly starts running on the next server in the list (Client obviously must sign in again). Whilst one server is fine at this time to run the two applications we have running when we ramp up our migration and have all our 140 applications running, I don’t think one server will be too happy with the load.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
LoadBalancers/Arr Servers: LB-01  (LB-02 DUPLICATED Server for redundancy). Default ARR URL ReWrite with Route to Server Farm Action.  [Image of LB/ARR URL ReWrite Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3KWM.png) Server Affinity Enabled Client Affinity enabled use hostname selected no Advanced Settings, no routing rules. ARR Default Proxy Settings [Image of Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z88u0.png)
Web/Application Servers WEB-01, WEB-02, WEB-03 FileSystem Shared using DFS All running on Shared Config's

The Applications would be as follows

https://www.domainname.com/application-name1

https://www.domainname.com/application-name2

...

Were the application launch page changes but the domain name stays the same

[Image of IIS Monitoring and Management Window showing distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCWOW.png)

If there is a setting you wish to verify please ask for them. I know people arent physchic but huge paragraphs of information never really help.
My hunch is it is something to do with the URL rewrite I have tried the settings in the below post to no avail.

[IIS ARR & load balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375868/iis-arr-load-balancing)

Comment: Without knowing how your ARR is configured, I don't think there's a lot we can do to help.

Comment: ` our applications kept a consistent connection between our client session and the application` Maybe this caused the issue. I think you can use sql server mode to store session information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)#sql-server-mode  Or directly use token to store shared and necessary information in each request.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check in with our SQL team and see if they can set something up on a test application and come back. I would assume this would allow us to turn off the Client/Server affinity and effectivly have out own "sticky session" through the SQL server rather than the Web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck 'Host Name Affinity' to dispatch to all your hosts

Comment: This very much looks to be the solution I was looking for. Coming back from a weeks holiday to this was fantastic we are now seeing some distribution. Going to leave it running for a few days then will mark as the answer. By the looks of it thanks for creating an account just to answer this question !!